# data type error on 'if' conditional statement

Tags: python

I am trying to print a grade with the score value for instance 0.85

At first I tried like this below:

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
float(score)

if 0.0 <= score <= 1.0:
    if score >= 0.9:
            print('A')

    elif score >= 0.8:
            print('B')

    elif score >= 0.7:
            print('C')

    elif score >= 0.6:
            print('D')

    else:
          print('F')  

else:
    print("ERROR")
```

But this returns an ERROR message.
Does anyone know why? 
I know I can do this like: **score = float(input("Enter Score: "))**

What the difference?

Comment: You are not assigning float(score) to score variable. You say "float(score)" and dont use it - you have to do "score = float(scoare)" or similar so the score is float not string. currently it is string because "score = input(..)" returns string

Comment: arrrggg.....My bad. Return to basics. Huge thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't store your `float(score)` in a variable . you can do it this way .

```
score_string = input("Enter Score: ")
score = float(score_string)

if 0.0 <= score <= 1.0:
    if score >= 0.9:
            print('A')

    elif score >= 0.8:
            print('B')

    elif score >= 0.7:
            print('C')

    elif score >= 0.6:
            print('D')

    else:
          print('F')  

else:
    print("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance(score, float)` or `type(score).__name__` to check, for example:

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
print(type(score).__name__)  # str
print(isinstance(score, float))
```

And you can use the method of `eval` that parsed and evaluated the variable as a Python expression.

```
for cur_exp in ('12345', '"abc"', '[1, 3, 5]', '("a", "b", "c")'):
    var = eval(cur_exp)
    print(type(var).__name__)  # int, str, list, tuple
```

By the way, I think this way is more readable, just for your reference

```
while 1:
    score = float(input("Enter Score: "))
    rank = (print('error'), exit()) if not 0.0 <= score <= 1.0 else \
        'A' if score >= 0.9 else \
        'B' if score >= 0.8 else \
        'C' if score >= 0.7 else 'D'
    print(rank)
```